# Default version package gets when Export-Version does not specify version

Tags: osgi

In OSGi, if I do not specify version in the Export-Package directive inside MANIFEST.MF, which version exported package will get?

1. Version equal to the bundle version?
2. Zero version (something like 0.0.0)?
3. Something else?

P.S. And here is the rationale behind this logic: https://mail.osgi.org/pipermail/osgi-dev/2010-August/002608.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For *Export-Package* the version defaults to *0.0.0*, and for *Import-Package* the version defaults to *[0.0.0, infinte]*. See also chapters 3.5.4 and 3.5.5 of the OSGi Core Specification.